# Dotnet Core Identity - Multi Tenant - Custom UserManager - NotSupportedException: No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider named 'Default' is registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am creating a dynamic multi tenant architecture where, I would have the TenantId in the query string while doing identity operations like login, forgot password and reset password. And I would have the TenantId in User Claims if the user is logged in.

I am creating my custom user manager like this,

```
public static UserManager<ApplicationUser> CreateUserManager(AppIdentityDbContext identityDbContext, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> options, string tenentId) {
        IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> hasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();            
        var validator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>();
        var validators = new List<UserValidator<ApplicationUser>> { validator };            
        ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> logger = 
        loggerFactory.CreateLogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var applicationUserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
            new ApplicationUserStore(identityDbContext, new ApplicationTenantIdProvider(tenentId)),
            options,
            hasher,
            validators,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            logger
        );
        return applicationUserManager;
    }
```

I have the logging working as expected - where I would create the usermanager calling the above static method.

However while doing the password reset, when calling the ResetPasswordAsync(user, passwordResetToken, password) with the custom UserManager I have created, I get this exception.

```
No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider named 'Default' is registered
```

I am passing IOptions options using DI from where I am calling the CreateUserManager method.

Here is the Startup.cs code regarding the Identity.

```
            services.AddScoped<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>, ApplicationRoleStore>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationUserStore>();                    
            services.AddScoped<TenantIdProviderService>();
            services.AddScoped(serviceProvider => new ApplicationTenantIdProvider(null));
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(o => {
                        o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
                        o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                        o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                        o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                        o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                        o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;                        
                    })
                    .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddAuthentication();
```

Here is the debugger output for my custom usermanager object - Tokens part
[image: Here is the debugger output for my custom usermanager object - Tokens part]

Is there an easy or correct method for setting the default IdentityOptions ( I think this is where I have problem ).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've added the default providers, but you haven't specified to use them, eg;

```cs
    services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>{
        options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultProvider;
        ...
    })
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: I did add this on the Startup.cs, still I get the same error.

Comment: You're seeing this exception; https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/605c522fa3e875fd6d3aefa783a71d1745b7e4c7/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1721 So for some reason "Default" isn't in the dictionary.

Comment: This certainly looks strange. The custom user manager's method FindByNameAsync ( i have this method in my custom user store ) - is working as expected. However any methods like ResetPasswordAsync does not for my custom user manager, but it works with my DI injected UserManager object!! Which is fine for me. So, it looks like I have a multi tenant system with a working Identity.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly looks strange. The custom user manager's method FindByNameAsync ( i have this method in my custom user store ) - is working as expected. However any methods like ResetPasswordAsync does not for my custom user manager, but it works with my DI injected UserManager object!! Which is fine for me. So, it looks like I have a multi tenant system with a working Identity.